# I am confused with braces inside braces. Please help me to figure out which are elements and which are sets in this set given in the picture .

Tags: multisets

Does 2 belongs to this set A? Does 2 an element  of  A..? 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plc8B.jpg)

Comment: Maybe tag as basic set theory.

Comment: It really annoys me that people downvote elementary maths questions, seemingly because they think "what is not obvious here?". But on another note, please rewrite the image using Latex. There's a reference here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Furthermore, in respect of your question, here's the bit I think you missed: Sets can themselves be elements of sets, so in your image you have sets which are also elements or a larger set.  So $2$ is not in itself an element of the set.  $2\in\{2\}$ means $2$ is an element of $\{2\}$, and $\{2\}\in A$ but $2\notin A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A = \{1, \{2,3\}, \{4\}\}$

i) Is $2 \in A$.  or Is $2$ an element of $A$?

Well.... What *are* the elements of $A$?  The elements of $A$ are: a)$1$,b)$\{2,3\}$ and c) $\{4\}$.  Are any of those three elements equal to $2$?  No.  None of them are equal to $2$.  So $2 \not \in A$.

ii) Is $\{2\}\in A$.  or Is $\{2\}$ an element of $A$?

Well.... What *are* the elements of $A$?  The elements of $A$ are: a)$1$,b)$\{2,3\}$ and c) $\{4\}$.  Are any of those three elements equal to $\{2\}$?  No.  None of them are equal to $\{2\}$.  So $\{2\} \not \in A$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to both questions is no.

$2$ is not an element of $A$ and { 2} is not an element of A either.

A has three elements, namely $1$, {2,3}, and {4} and none of the above is among them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the outermost brackets. What's left is your elements, separted by commas. So here neither $2$ nor $\{2\}$ are elements.